# xamarin android custom expandible list view

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin

I would like to know how can I create an expandable list view as shown in the diagram below where it would load all the dates and transactions in that specif date and the that transaction can be expanded to view all categories in a horizontal recycle view.

Many Thanks

[Custom List View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkS3a.png)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a demo based on your screenshot, you could refer to it.

MainActivity.cs

```
    namespace ExpandListViewDemo1
{
    [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
            var listView = FindViewById<ExpandableListView>(Resource.Id.myExpandableListview);
            listView.SetAdapter(new ExpandableDataAdapter(this, Data.SampleData()));
        }
    }
}
```

ExpandableDataAdapter.cs

```
    namespace ExpandListViewDemo1
{



     class ExpandableDataAdapter : BaseExpandableListAdapter
    {

        readonly Activity Context;
        public ExpandableDataAdapter(Activity newContext, List<Data> newList) : base()
        {
            Context = newContext;
            DataList = newList;
        }

        protected List<Data> DataList { get; set; }

        public override View GetGroupView(int groupPosition, bool isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            View header = convertView;
            if (header == null)
            {
                header = Context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.ListGroup, null);
            }
            header.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.DataHeader).Text = ((char)(65 + groupPosition)).ToString();

            return header;
        }

        public override View GetChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, bool isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            View row = convertView;
            if (row == null)
            {
                row = Context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.DataListItem, null);
            }
            string newId = "", newValue = "";
            GetChildViewHelper(groupPosition, childPosition, out newId, out newValue);
            row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.DataId).Text = newId;
            row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.DataValue).Text = newValue;

            return row;
            //throw new NotImplementedException ();
        }

        public override int GetChildrenCount(int groupPosition)
        {
            char letter = (char)(65 + groupPosition);
            List<Data> results = DataList.FindAll((Data obj) => obj.Id[0].Equals(letter));
            return results.Count;
        }

        public override int GroupCount
        {
            get
            {
                return 26;
            }
        }

        private void GetChildViewHelper(int groupPosition, int childPosition, out string Id, out string Value)
        {
            char letter = (char)(65 + groupPosition);
            List<Data> results = DataList.FindAll((Data obj) => obj.Id[0].Equals(letter));
            Id = results[childPosition].Id;
            Value = results[childPosition].Value;
        }

        #region implemented abstract members of BaseExpandableListAdapter

        public override Java.Lang.Object GetChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override long GetChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
        {
            return childPosition;
        }

        public override Java.Lang.Object GetGroup(int groupPosition)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override long GetGroupId(int groupPosition)
        {
            return groupPosition;
        }

        public override bool IsChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
        {
        return true;
    }

        public override bool HasStableIds
        {
            get
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

DataAdapter.cs

```
 class DataAdapter : BaseAdapter<Data>
    {
        readonly Activity context;

        public DataAdapter(Activity newContext, List<Data> newData) : base()
        {
            context = newContext;
            DataList = newData;
        }

        public List<Data> DataList { get; set; }

        public override int Count
        {
            get
            {
                return DataList.Count;
            }
        }

        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            View newView = convertView; // re-use an existing view, if one is available
            if (newView == null) // otherwise create a new one
                newView = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.DataListItem, null);
            newView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.DataId).Text = DataList[position].Id;
            newView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.DataValue).Text = DataList[position].Value;
            return newView;
        }

        public override long GetItemId(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }

        public override Data this[int index]
        {
            get
            {
                return DataList[index];
            }
        }
    }
```

Data.cs

```
class Data
{
    public Data()
    {
    }

    public static List<Data> SampleData()
    {
        var newDataList = new List<Data>();
        newDataList.Add(new Data("Alabama", "Montegomery"));
        newDataList.Add(new Data("Alaska", "Juneau"));
        newDataList.Add(new Data("Arizona", "Pheonix"));
        newDataList.Add(new Data("Arkansas", "Little Rock"));
        newDataList.Add(new Data("California", "Sacramento"));
        newDataList.Add(new Data("Colorado", "Denver"));
        newDataList.Add(new Data("Connecticut", "Hartford"));
        newDataList.Add(new Data("Delaware", "Dover"));
        newDataList.Add(new Data("Florida", "Tallahassee"));
        newDataList.Add(new Data("Georgia", "Atlanta"));
        newDataList.Add(new Data("Hawaii", "Honolulu"));
        newDataList.Add(new Data("Idaho", "Boise"));
        newDataList.Add(new Data("Illinois", "Springfield"));
        newDataList.Add(new Data("Indiana", "Indianapolis"));
        newDataList.Add(new Data("Iowa", "Des Moines"));
        newDataList.Add(new Data("Kansas", "Topeka"));

        newDataList.Add(new Data("Kentucky", "Frankfort"));
        newDataList.Add(new Data("Louisiana", "Baton Rouge"));
        newDataList.Add(new Data("Maine", "Augusta"));
        newDataList.Add(new Data("Maryland", "Annapolis"));
        newDataList.Add(new Data("Massachusetts", "Boston"));

        newDataList.Add(new Data("Michigan", "Lansing"));
        newDataList.Add(new Data("Minnesota", "Saint Paul"));
        newDataList.Add(new Data("Mississippi", "Jackson"));
        newDataList.Add(new Data("Missouri", "Jefferson City"));
        newDataList.Add(new Data("Montana", "Helena"));
        newDataList.Add(new Data("Nebraska", "Lincoln"));
        newDataList.Add(new Data("Nevada", "Carson City"));
        newDataList.Add(new Data("New Hampshire", "Concord"));
        newDataList.Add(new Data("New Jersey", "Trenton"));
        newDataList.Add(new Data("New Mexico", "Santa Fe"));
        newDataList.Add(new Data("New York", "Albany"));
        newDataList.Add(new Data("North Calorina", "Raleigh"));
        newDataList.Add(new Data("North Dakota", "Bismarck"));
        newDataList.Add(new Data("Ohio", "Columbus"));
        newDataList.Add(new Data("Oklahoma", "Oklahoma City"));
        newDataList.Add(new Data("Oregon", "Salem"));
        newDataList.Add(new Data("Pennsylvania", "Harrisburg"));
        newDataList.Add(new Data("Rhode Island", "Providence"));
        newDataList.Add(new Data("South Carolina", "Columbia"));
        newDataList.Add(new Data("South Dakota", "Pierre"));
        newDataList.Add(new Data("Tennessee", "Nashville"));
        newDataList.Add(new Data("Texas", "Austin"));
        newDataList.Add(new Data("Utah", "Salt Lake City"));
        newDataList.Add(new Data("Vermont", "Montpelier"));
        newDataList.Add(new Data("Virginia", "Richmond"));
        newDataList.Add(new Data("Washington", "Olympia"));
        newDataList.Add(new Data("West Virginia", "Charleston"));
        newDataList.Add(new Data("Wisconsin", "Madison"));
        newDataList.Add(new Data("Wyoming", "Cheyenne"));
        return newDataList;
    }

    public Data(string newId = "Temporary Id", string newValue = "Temporary Data")
    {
        Id = newId;
        Value = newValue;
    }

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Resources\layout\activity_main.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
     <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/myExpandableListview"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Resources\layout\DataListItem.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/DataRow"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/DataId"
        android:text="Id"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:background="#ff5684e3"
        android:paddingStart="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Value"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/DataValue"
        android:background="#ff366300"

        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Resources\layout\ListGroup.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/DataHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="DataHeader"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingStart="50dp"
        android:paddingLeft="50dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is running screenshot.

[image]

If you have any questions about this demo, you could post it here.

Comment: That great i would be able to add the transactions and the list of categories under them as a horizontal list view .. But how about the date of transaction ? As i think i need a three level view ? For example under 14 December i can have 2 transactions and under each transaction is its horizontal list view

Comment: @AliAlma , if you need a three level view ,you could refer to this link.https://github.com/Billycool1020/Three-Level-ExpandableListView